# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'loginuser' available as request attribute

Tags: spring

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("Page/Login.do")
public class HomeController
{
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    protected String showLoginPage(HttpServletRequest req,BindingResult result) throws Exception
    {
        loginuser lu=new loginuser();
        lu.setLoginn("Amit");
        System.out.println(lu.getLoginn());
        return "Login";
    }
}
```

Above code is ##HomeController.java##

loginuser.java

```
package Com.Site.Name.Order;

public class loginuser
{
        private String Loginn;


        public String getLoginn()
                {
            System.out.println("hi i m in login get");
            return Loginn;
        }

        public void setLoginn(String loginn) 
                {
            System.out.println("I m in Loin set");
            Loginn = loginn;
        }   
}
```

My JSP PAGE IS

Login.jsp

```
<form:form action="Login.do" method="post" commandName="loginuser">
    <div id="Getin">
        <img alt="" src="Image/loginttt.png">
    </div>
    <div id="login">    
    </div>

    <form:input path="Loginn"/>
    <input type="submit" value="LOGIN"/>
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a `Model` attribute (`commandName`) but there is no such attribute added to the model or request attributes. You need to add it. Also, the `BindingResult` in your handler makes no sense. Remove it.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
protected String showLoginPage(HttpServletRequest req, Model model) throws Exception
{
    loginuser lu=new loginuser();
    lu.setLoginn("Amit");
    System.out.println(lu.getLoginn());
    model.addAttribute("loginuser", lu);
    return "Login";
}
```

The `Model` attributes are added to the request attributes and are therefore available in the `jsp`.

Comment: @user2312546 Model attributes are an abstraction from the `HttpServletRequest` attributes. Please edit your question and show me what you've modified and how.

Comment: I changed jsp <form:from> tag to <form:form action="Login.do" method="post" modelAttribute="lu">

Comment: I changed jsp <form:from> tag to <form:form action="Login.do" method="post" modelAttribute="loginuser"> i ogt jsp error An exception occurred processing JSP page /Login.jsp at line 22

Comment: @user2312546 How does that reflect what I propose in my answer? Change your controller handler method.

Comment: i want to take login value from page and print in my console

Comment: @user2312546 I have no idea what that has to do with the problem. Please replace your handler method with the one I have in my answer.

Comment: i want to take login value from page and print in my console pls give any complit example...

Comment: @user2312546 Consider accepting answers to your questions. It will motivate people to help you in the future.